# firebase auth verifySessionCookie is slow

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I secured a REST API with firebase auth and noticed that the verification of the session cookie took most of the time when serving a request. This is was the call looks like:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, CHECK_REVOKED)
  .then(decodedClaim => /* continue serving the request... */)
```

The profiler shows a rather slow HTTPS request to the firebase backend for every verification call.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `CHECK_REVOKED` parameter passed to the verification function. It will enforce that firebase always checks the authentication backend for revoked sessions (e.g. when a password change happened). When `CHECK_REVOKED` is set to `false` (or not passed at all, it's optional), the firebase auth will cache session verification results.